# Session, cookies and ids

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

It was suggested to me to use sessions for cross page storage, and maintain the session ID by storing it in a GET parameter or cookie.

What's the safest way to save data into a session and make it last forever (like login informations)?

Comment: To make sessions last longer **is insecure**

Comment: To answer your question, one have to use **both** sessions and cookies, each thing for it's purpose. **Not** trying to make one from another just because of ignorance.

Comment: A session is finite by definition. So a session that lasts forever is not a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are a standard feature in PHP. Start from [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to read some detail about how sessions are handled in PHP. Anyway, be aware that even session aren't 100% safe. There are a number of security concerns even about sessions (you can read something about [session security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php), [Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), [Session Poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_poisoning) to understand the security implications of sessions).

Comment: Nothing on the web is 100% safe, ever! So basically what you are trying to say is: RTFM?

Comment: No I'm just saying that you have to evaluate risks. An strongly-encrypted cookie can be more safe than a plain session in some scenario. You'll find a detailed discussion on the page I've linked

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I entirely understand your question, but you may be mixing up two things. The `sid` GET parameter is used as a fallback session ID when cookies are disabled. Both the GET parameter and the cookie do the same thing, but storing the session ID in the cookie doesn't clutter the URL, which is why this is the preferred method.

When you store session data using `$_SESSION` in PHP, the data gets stored *only* internally. It is not transmitted to the user's browser. Only the cookie (or sid) containing the session ID ever leaves the server.

Comment: I didn't down-voted, but you did not understand my question. I do not want to use cookies because they are not safe (they can easily be edited), so i'd like to store my vars (internally) but make the session last more than a unique use.

Comment: @Charlie but that's exactly what sessions are for. The  cookie is there only to tell which session belongs to which user. The cookie is unsafe but that doesn't matter. You don't store any sensitive data in it.

Comment: Could you explain with examples?

Comment: @Charlie not You can assume that if you follow PHP's standard session handling practices, the basic mechanism behind it (which works with a session ID in a cookie or sid parameter) is *reasonably* safe. There are pitfalls (there are discussions about them on SO, @ass3mbler links to some of them) but session handling (maybe in conjunction with a SSL connection) is generally the standard way to go.

Comment: @Charlie: Session uses cookies to identify which session is your session from all current session. so that the session will not conflict. They store session id in cookie and when you request to web page they read the your current session data by session id stored on your browser

Comment: @Pekka, if i do not remember wrong, i think that sessions die after the browser is closed. So, how could sessions be a replacement for cookies (a part from the fact that session id is stored into a cookie) while they last only for one use?

Comment: look at the comments in the page session_set_cookie_params. One user posted what I think you need, it it's only about the expiration of the session: ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $Lifetime);
ini_set("session.gc_divisor", "1");
ini_set("session.gc_probability", "1");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
ini_set("session.save_path", $DirectoryPath);
session_start();

Comment: Thanks Ass3mbler, it was really usefull. Just one question: Setting a different lifetime for sessions affect the safe of a session?

Comment: Not very much. This is an interesting question because it involves methods for tying the session with the user IP and browser informations reliably, there is some info in the pages I've linked, but the difference in security is not very high

Comment: That's disgusting side of stackoverflow. Noobs and lamers just outnumber good guys.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between a cookie and a session is that the session data is stored on the server side while the cookie data is stored on the client side. But as sending sensitive data between server and client implies significant security concerns (data tampering, eavesdropping, etc.), the data should rather be stored on the server side.

But to associate a client with a session you need some kind of identifier. That’s where the session ID comes into use. Because since the HTTP is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_server) (i.e. each request is an independent transaction that is unrelated to any previous request), there is no native way to identify a client just by its requests.

So instead of storing the data in a cookie on client side and have it sent back with every request, you just store the session ID on the client side and have it sent back with every request. That is way more secure as sensitive data is not being sent over the wire. All that is sent is the session ID (here you can use either the URL or a cookie as well).

But now as the session ID is the only information to associate a client to a session, it’s the session ID that has become some kind of sensitive data that needs to be protected. Here you need some kind of [session authentication and management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management) to avoid attacks on the session.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a community, users post links and external images.

To keep the session alive the page makes use of GET instead of cookies.

So: a user watches an external image or clicks on a external link.
The owner of the external ressource will now be able to read the REFERER, and by this he can see the session-ID and hijack the session.

That's why most communities and similar pages put a proxy between the page and the external ressource, they strip the SESSION-ID if it is stored via GET.`<edited/>`

Comment: MMm, no. I'd retrieve the session id and make it avaiable only by the related user who first have to login. Sessions would be used only for login things... i probably misunderstand your answer.

Comment: But to keep the session alive(let the user stay logged in) you need to transfer the session-ID over the URL, that's the problem. If the user went to a page with external content, the session-ID can be retrieved on the external server, because usually the requesting URL is available there as HTTP_REFERER. It's no problem if somebody fakes a cookie, if he doesn't know a valid session-ID nothing will happen. The problem is if he knows a valid session-ID, and this will be much easier if you use GET instead of cookies.

Comment: "a proxy between the page and the external ressource"? what are you talking about? Got an example of such a community?

Comment: vbulletin for example has done it earlier before they rebuild their session-managment with security-tokens.

Comment: Done WHAT? Suppose I've downloaded vbulletin code and run it. Where is that proxy takes location?

Comment: Done what? Instead of directly linking to an external ressource submitted by users they linked to something like `externalcontent.php?ressource=someexternalressource` where a redirecting to that external ressource has been done. Can't tell you where to look, as I said they rebuild the session-managment sometimes and I don't have an old version available.

Comment: ok, got it now, sorry. If you edit your question, I'll be able remove a downvote.

Comment: It’s not a proxy but a dereferrer.